# How to make a container as a radio button in Flutter and make sure it doesn't deselect

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have used a package [group_button 4.2.1](https://pub.dev/packages/group_button) but once i select the textfields the radio buttons deselect and i have to select again, i have tried using the controller property of the Widget but i didn't get it to work.

I was thinking if i can make a container from scratch that is a radio button and can retain the value once i finish filling the form to be submitted to my firestore database.

[image]

Comment: The radio buttons are not visible in the image.

Comment: @CalvinGonsalves the concept of radio buttons is featured with container like buttons instaed of the normal radio buttons, Cupertino style radio buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use List of button text and keep tract of `selectedIndex`.

Run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=64f77a348f34f3c6c9f7e09264b219b1)

```dart
 int? _selectedValueIndex;
  List<String> buttonText = ["ForSale", "For rent"];

  Widget button({required String text, required int index}) {
    return InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _selectedValueIndex = index;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        color: index == _selectedValueIndex ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: index == _selectedValueIndex ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Inside build method to use this,

```dart
 Row(
  children: [
    ...List.generate(
      buttonText.length,
      (index) => button(
        index: index,
        text: buttonText[index],
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: you are blessed that was quick

Comment: how about if i want to convert them to a check box https://stackoverflow.com/q/70840751/10796813