# Instance of 'Future<dynamic>' in Flutter when returning Firestore value

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I thought this was going to be far easier than it turned out but I have a collection called 'USER_TABLE' with userID, email, first name and lastName.

I want to retrieve the firstName from the database and then use it in a Text widget

I am printing the firstName for debug purposes and im getting the right value but its displaying in my app as Instance of 'Future

Any ideas as to what im doing wrong? Getting no errors currently

Thanks

CODE:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:moodful/components/authentication_service.dart';
import 'package:moodful/components/background.dart';
import 'package:moodful/Screens/Login/login_screen.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // This size provide us total height and width of our screen

    var firstName = getData();

    //return Scaffold(
    return BackgroundLogoRight(
      text: "Home",
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Spacer(),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 10,
                  child: Text(
                    "$firstName \n\n "
                    "Glad you're back, please enter a mood for today.\n\n "
                    "Be sure to check the insights page for the most up to date mood analysis\n\n"
                    "The more you know the more control you have",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return LoginScreen(); // change to return something sensible
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }, // handle your image tap here
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/recordMoodLogo.jpg",
                    width: size.width * 0.5,

                    fit: BoxFit.cover, // this is the solution for border

                    height: 110.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  getData() async {
    var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    DocumentSnapshot variable = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('USER_TABLE')
        .doc(currentUser!.uid)
        .get();
    print(variable['firstName']);
    return variable['firstName'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When fetching data from Firebase or from any other source, that will be done in an asynchronous way, therefore it will take some time until the data is fetched. In Flutter, you can use a widget called `FutureBuilder` for these asynchronous calls. For example:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>? _fetchedData;

  @override
   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchedData = getData();
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    FutureBuilder(
      future: _fetchedData,
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return BackgroundLogoRight(
            text: "Home",
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Spacer(),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 10,
                        child: Text(
                          "${snapshot.data!.data()!["firstname"]} \n\n "
                          "Glad you're back, please enter a mood for today.\n\n "
                          "Be sure to check the insights page for the most up to date mood analysis\n\n"
                          "The more you know the more control you have",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) {
                                return LoginScreen(); // change to return something sensible
                              },
                            ),
                          );
                        }, // handle your image tap here
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/recordMoodLogo.jpg",
                          width: size.width * 0.5,

                          fit: BoxFit.cover, // this is the solution for border

                          height: 110.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
        else {return CircularProgressIndicator();}
      },
    );
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getData() async {
    var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('USER_TABLE')
        .doc(currentUser!.uid)
        .get();
  }
```

The `getData()` method will return the data inside the `userid` document and then using the `FutureBuilder` widget you can display the name of the user. Since this is asynchronous, it will be in the waiting state so the `circularprogressindicator` will appear and then it will be in the completed state when the data is returned. Also obtain the `future` in the `initState`

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Check:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: best approach and the easiest wanted to write the same

Comment: can you please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70840751/how-to-make-a-container-as-a-check-box-in-flutter-and-make-sure-it-doesnt-desel

Comment: Yeah that worked perfectly, thanks for that. I had looked online at future builder but wasn't understanding it. Thanks for such a detailed response